# symfony dql does not pass aliasses from joins between functions

Tags: php, symfony, join, dql

I am trying to build a query with DQL that is split up in several functions, so I can re-use these functions again and again for different queries.

So far this worked great, until I needed to re-use an alias from a join

Let's say I have these two functions:

```
public function addEquipmentSubType(QueryBuilder $builder): QueryBuilder
{
  return $builder
    ->andWhere(est.code = :code) 
    ->leftJoin('q.equipmentSubType', 'est')
    ->addSelect('est')
    ->setParameter('code', '123');
}
```

and then this one:

```
public function search(QueryBuilder $builder): QueryBuilder
{
  return $builder
    ->andWhere('q.projectNumber LIKE :search OR est.name LIKE :search')
}
```

This triggers an error, saying 'est' is not defined. It seems like the only way to fix this, is to join equipmentSubtype again, but this causes the eventual query to have 2 joins with the same table.

Is there a way to pass those table aliasses from function to function so I can reuse the join?

Comment: It's probably triggering an error because it's not quoted. `est` does not exist in PHP.

Comment: How are you calling the two methods? As long as it's the same QueryBuilder instance then it should work fine, it's not like the builder has any idea that the clauses were even added in different places. Although obviously a method that adds an alias has to be called first.

Comment: I call addEquipmentSupType first, and right after that, if a search parameter is set, I call search. Nothing inbetween. The funny thing is, if I use ->getQuery()->getSQL() paste that directly in PphpMyAdmin, the query works fine, even though it gives the not defined est error when I call ->getQuery->getResult()

Comment: Maybe update the question with the exact error message.  Something else might be going on.  Like iainn, I don't see any reason for a failure unless you are somehow switching query builders.  Can't help but wonder if it's because you are using a parameter called search twice.